# How to use a different javax.servlet-api?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I'm attempting to debug some code to ensure I'm setting some HttpServletResponse 
 headers correctly.  To do that I just want to print out the headers from the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.  The request side works just fine, but the response does not because response.getHeaderNames() is undefined.

```
    private void printDebug(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("----- Request ---------");
        Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()).forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + ": " + request.getHeader(n.toString())));

        System.out.println("----- Response ---------");
        response.getHeaderNames().forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + ": " + response.getHeader(n)));
}
```

Using:
Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Tomcat v.7.0
jdk1.8.0_112

Project Facets: 
Dynamic Web Module 3.1

And in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But some where I'm sure there is a configuration I'm missing that's pointing Eclipse to us the 2.5 javax.servlet-api by default but I just don't know where to look or how to change it.

**Update:** If I uncheck "Dynamic Web Module" and then do a maven update, maven sets Dynamic Web Module back to 2.5
[image]

How can I get this getHeaderNames() to work?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Does your code compile? Where do you get the error?

Comment: Does not compile because: `response.getHeaderNames() is undefined`

Comment: Open the declaration of `HttpServletResponse` and check in package explorer where does it come from.

Comment: Its coming from servlet-api-2.5.jar in the Maven Dependencies

Comment: I added more snippets from my pom.xml file I don't understand why 2.5 is still being used here but it is.

Comment: What is the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api` ? though I can already see that `jstl` is the problem.

Comment: @Oleg your questions led me to change javax.servlet jstl dependency by adding an exclusion for javax.servlet servlet-api.  I think this fixed it and if you post an answer I'll happily give you credit.  Thank you very much.

Comment: That's ok thanks, I'm still not sure what was the *exact* problem and what fixed it so I don't really know what to post.

Comment: Exact problem was that the `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>` was causing maven to include javax.servlet-api 2.5.  Adding an exclusion to this dependency `<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>java.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion></exclusions>` fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that when I compiled the javax.servlet-api v2.5 was being used even though I was explicitly including 3.1 in my pom.

First, as @Oleg suggested, I opened the declaration of HttpServletResponse and checked the package explorer to find out where HttpServletResponse was coming from.  It was coming from servlet-api-2.5.jar in the Maven Dependencies.  Which is what I thought was happening but not what I wanted.

Next, I went through all the Dependency Hierarchy to find which entry in the pom was including the 2.5 version.  Where I noticed that the jstl artifact was including the old version I didn't want.

So I changed this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>java.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
     </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Finally, I did a Maven update and a clean compile just to be sure and it worked.

Hope this helps someone else!

Thank you @Oleg.